# How to set custom context for docker.build in jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to adapt a docker build for jenkins.  I'm following our docker-compose file and I'm creating a Jenkinsfile that is creating each container and linking them together.  The problem I'm running into is that the docker-compose files declare a context that is not where the Dockerfile is.  As far as I understand, jenkins will set the context to where the Dockerfile is, which puts files to be copied in a different relative location depending on whether the jenkinsfile or docker-compose file is building.

The folder structure is:

```
workspace
    |-docker
        |-db
           |-Dockerfile
           |-entrypoint.sh
```

This is how the Dockerfile declares the COPY instruction for the file in question

```
COPY docker/db/entrypoint.sh /
```

This is how my jenkinsfile builds the file.  Which to my knowledge puts the context at that directory

```
docker.build("db", "${WORKSPACE}/docker/db")
```

the docker-compose file declares it like:

```
db:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: docker/db/Dockerfile
```

which puts the context at the root of the project.

Is there any way to tell a jenkinsfile to use the same context as the docker-compose file so that the Dockerfile's COPY instruction can remain unchanged and valid for both Jenkins and docker-compose?  If that's not possible, does anyone know of any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It turns out that I was pulling a previous version (1.6) of the docker-pipeline-plugin.  The function in question has been since updated (1.7) to allow the second parameter to designate a Dockerfile location outside the context.

The updated statement in my Jenkinsfile is:

```
return docker.build("db", "-f docker/db/Dockerfile .")
```

And this allows my container to build without modifying the expected context of the developer's docker-compose or Dockerfiles.

Comment: I'm I the only one that thinks docker integration in Jenkins utterly sucks? I have version 1.14 of the docker pipeline plugin and it seems the second argument has already been removed again :-(

Comment: @schneida I'm running 1.13 at this point, and the format in this answer is still working for me.  You could try downgrading to 1.13 to see if it makes a difference.  Otherwise, this format has also worked for me `db -f docker/db/Dockerfile` which combines the arguments, and leaves out the context

Answer (score 1):

The build() method builds the Dockerfile in the current directory by default. This can be overridden by providing a directory path containing a Dockerfile as the second argument of the build() method, for example:

```
node {
    checkout scm
    def testImage = docker.build("test-image", "./dockerfiles/test") 

    testImage.inside {
        sh 'make test'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To specify the path of the dockerfile the dir{} block worked for me

```
stage('docker build') {
            steps {
                dir('/path/to/docker/file/'){
                    script{
                        dockerImage = docker.build("imageName")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the dir block because you'll need to perform actions like COPY, where you must be in the location

So Use this Code

```
stage('Build') {
        steps {
            dir('/path/to/docker/file/'){ // put the path of Dockerfile
                script{
                    my_images = docker.build("Your_Image")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Omnit the `context` item on `docker-compose` so it defaults to the location of the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Following syntax should work:
docker.build('ContainerTag''-f DockerFilePath Context'
example: docker.build('quay.io/AppContianer:1.0.0' '-f dockerfileDir/Dockerfile.test dockerfileDir')